# How to redirect a website using iptables in my router?

Tags: linux, iptables

I have two device：A router and a computer which in lan.
router ip is 192.168.1.1        computer is 192.168.1.10.
I want to accomplish this:when i type www.geolgle.com in browser bar，it can be redirect to www.facebook.com

when i using this command in my router:

```
#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80  -d 158.69.143.114 -j DNAT --to-destination 67.228.126.62
#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443  -d 158.69.143.114 -j DNAT --to-destination 67.228.126.62
```

But it is only can redirect 158.69.143.114.when i type 158.69.143.114 in browser bar ，it work. type www.geolgle.com ，it not work.

Please let me know why it happen and what should do

Comment: facebook (and geolgle.com it seems) are hidden behind content delivery networks (aka CDN) so their addresses are very dynamic. You cannot reroute them with such a static scheme. In addition the host name is put in the HTTP request, so the HTTP request is likely to fail on the new target host. You would need a proxy to do this properly.

Comment: yes，I trace the network ,It seems there are something package return  and nothing content .But why it  work when i type IP address？Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect by hostname, not by IP Address, so `iptables` is the wrong tool for this job.

Use a web proxy, e.g. [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), that is capable of redirecting URLs requested by client machines to another destination.

You can write your own redirector (half a dozen or so lines of awk or perl will be enough for a simple redirector script), or you can use one of several existing redirectors (most come with rules to block ads, spyware, and other malware, and/or censoring rules for enforcing acceptable use policies for workplaces and schools) and add or replace their rules with your own.

Squid is available pre-packaged for most, if not all, Linux distributions.  And some of the well-known redirectors (e.g. [squidGuard](http://www.squidguard.org/) and [Jesred](http://www.linofee.org/~jel/webtools/jesred/)) are also available as packages.

Note: if your router is not a unix/linux box capable of running squid, then you will have to run squid on another machine.  Also, web traffic from machines other than the proxy should either be blocked on the router, transproxied, or re-directed to a local (internal network) web page that documents how to set a proxy in various browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ! I realized that I may need another way to replace iptables solution.

Comment: But I do not understand why iptables can not handle hostname. iptables rules can be set  likes ： iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443  -d www.geogle.com -j DNAT --to-destination 67.228.126.62

Comment: when i type www.geogle.com，it still not work.

Comment: when you give iptables a hostname for `-s` or `-d`, it does an **immediate** DNS lookup on that hostname and uses the **first** IP address returned and the rule will only apply to that **single** IP address.  Obviously, that won't work for hostnames with multiple IP addresses....this is especially true for hostnames pointing to a CDN that can dynamically assign IP addresses on any arbitrary criterion (client's region, nearest host, CDN plan paid for by their customer, phase of the moon, whatever)

Comment: I understand.Thanks and send my best regard.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ nslookup www.geolgle.com
Server:         10.220.231.10
Address:        10.220.231.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.geolgle.com
Address: 103.224.212.222
```

Perhaps you should use the correct IP address?

Comment: yes,enn..I use geolgle and facebook to for a example,not really the IP address